# How can I build this kind of UI, from AWS Comprehend Medical?

Tags: reactjs, nlp, visualization, amazon-comprehend

I'm using the AWS machine learning service Comprehend Medical to analyse clinical texts and extract data.

Some context info (skippable maybe):

This is the type of input:

```
Pt is 40yo mother, highschool teacher 
HPI : Sleeping trouble on present dosage of Clonidine. Severe Rash  on face and leg, slightly itchy  
Meds : Vyvanse 50 mgs po at breakfast daily, 
            Clonidine 0.2 mgs -- 1 and 1 / 2 tabs po qhs 
HEENT : Boggy inferior turbinates, No oropharyngeal lesion 
Lungs : clear 
Heart : Regular rhythm 
Skin :  Mild erythematous eruption to hairline 

Follow-up as scheduled
```

This is the kind of output I get from AWS:

```
{
    "Entities": [
        {
            "Id": 0,
            "BeginOffset": 6,
            "EndOffset": 10,
            "Score": 0.9984116554260254,
            "Text": "40yo",
            "Category": "PROTECTED_HEALTH_INFORMATION",
            "Type": "AGE",
            "Traits": []
        },
        {
            "Id": 1,
            "BeginOffset": 19,
            "EndOffset": 37,
            "Score": 0.28823626041412354,
            "Text": "highschool teacher",
            "Category": "PROTECTED_HEALTH_INFORMATION",
            "Type": "PROFESSION",
            "Traits": []
        },
         ...
```

Then I would like to render this kind of UI, the same way AWS does in their console to represent Comprehend medical outputs (see the image) :
[AWS Console Comprehend Medical output representation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jnvcl.png)

[I managed to tag the text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ixPDF.png). **But I have no idea in how to make the tagged arrows**: represent those dependecies between html elements.

I have tried some react libraries like **Taggy**(only do tagging) and explored some other solutions like **Spacey** (will require SSR and not even the same output of tags + tagged arrows ),

Anyone could suggest an approach to do this kind of tagged arrows between those html components?

Thank you ma people.

Comment: Try a diagramming lib: https://github.com/projectstorm/react-diagrams

Comment: @walter, Please let me know if you find any better solution for this.